# Mongoose FindOneAndUpdate override my value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was trying to set up bank account like for a Discord server and here is my problem:

I have this schema:

```
var ladderboardSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    victories: {type: Number, default: 0},
    bank: {type: Number, default: 5000},
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

followed by this model :

```
var ladderboardPlayer = mongoose.model('Ladder', ladderboardSchema);
```

So as you can see, the basic value of my bank should be 5000, and when my function is called, I want my bank value to increase for the specified amount for this player!

```
function setMoney(playerName, amount){
    var query = {name: playerName};
    var update = {$inc: {bank:amount} };
    var options = {upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true};
    ladderboardPlayer.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, doc){
        if(!err) console.error('updated!');
    });
}
```

For example, lets say I run `setMoney('John', 500);`, MongoDB will return me:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57a67d1e874dfe1eb4163888"), "name" : "John", "bank" : 500, "__v" : 0, "victories" : 0, "date" : ISODate("2016-08-07T00:13:18.192Z") }
```

It should return 5500 but im kinda lost since I already tried a lot of solutions and none of works even if 'new' and 'setDefaultsOnInsert' are set to `true`

Comment: Which version of mongoose you use?

Comment: I'm using the 4.5.8 VERSION